# VS2013 Web Admin Tool throwing Access Denied Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2013

I have the Web Site Administration Tool running, but when I click on the 'security' tab, I get the following error...

**Unable to connect to SQL Server database**

I have the following in the web.config of my project.  What am I missing?

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer"
  connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=myDB;User Id=myUser;Password=password123;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have already run the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the aspnet_regsql tool successfully as well.

Comment: First, I'd like to ask is this really what you need to do?  Are you using the old, obsolete Membership system or are you using the new ASP.NET Identity?  If you don't know, then you need to figure this out.  If you're using Identity, then you are on the wrong path as WSAT does not work with Identity, only the Old Membership System.

Comment: I'm using Identity.  It is a ASP.NET Web Forms website on .NET 4.5.

Comment: I'm trying to create a user management system, first.  My client needs to be able to manually add users and set specific profile attributes.

Comment: The Web Site Administration Tool does not work with Identity.  It's a legacy tool that can only function with the old Membership system.  So don't even bother with trying to make it work, it won't.  It can't.  You will have to either develop your own user management pages, or try to find a third party tool (I don't know of any, but I do know they exist, but they will probably be more work than just doing it yourself).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I started down this road by trying to enable roles and must have run across some legacy articles. Thanks!